# Hide Shortcodes From Wordpress RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, shortcode

I added Adsense to my content via shortcodes. But Adsense codes appears in RSS too. How can I hide shortcodes from RSS Feed and show only for in posts ?

I am using sahifa wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to alter how the RSS is output.

All the RSS styling files are located in the `wp-includes` folder and are titled as follows:

- feed-rss2.php
- feed-rss.php
- feed-rdf.php
- feed-atom.php
- feed-atom-comments.php
- feed-rss2-comments.php

Then within these files, you need to find where it calls the function `the_excerpt_rss()`. This calls out the content in excerpt format.

You will need to enclose this in a function called `strip_shortcodes()`.

As an example from `feed-atom.php` line 70:

```
<summary type="<?php html_type_rss(); ?>"><![CDATA[<?php strip_shortcodes(the_excerpt_rss()); ?>]]></summary>
```

Hope this helps